# Limit to the number of explanatory variables that R's BMA package can handle?

Tags: r, linear-regression, bayesian

Using R's BMA (Bayesian Model Averaging) package, I want to run the following code:

```
result = bic.glm(x,y,prior.param = c(1,1,1,1,0.5,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,1,1,1,1,1,0.5,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.5,1), glm.family="gaussian",factor.type=TRUE)
```

When my `x` matrix has 29 variables (and my vector of prior parameters also has length 29), the `bic.glm` function works. However, when I added a 30th variable to `x` and add a 30th value to my `prior.param` vector, I get the following error:

```
Error in dropcols(leaps.x, y, glm.family, wt, maxCol) : dropped == 0
```

Does this mean there is a maximum number of explanatory variables that this function can handle? Or does the error have to do with something completely different (perhaps missing values/NAs)? Guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem in a dataset without NA's so lets exclude that explanation... Still searching for a solution. Maybe if you provide a reproducible example, we can work towards it? If not, I'll just start a new question with one.